# Do I have to use the same private key for SAN SSL Certificate?

Tags: ssl, nginx

I am trying to install COMODO SAN SSL Certificate for an alternative name. This domain is on a different server.

I am having the following problem:

```
nginx: [emerg] SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(“/etc/nginx/ssl/ssl-bundle.crt”) failed (SSL: error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch)
```

I checked out a lot of articles, most of the people recommend to regenerate the ssl bundle, and it could be a problem of the order.

I have followed both these tutorials:

1. http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2015/02/28/installing-comodo-positivessl-certificates-on-nginx/
2. https://gist.github.com/bradmontgomery/6487319

I am still having the same problem. Do I have to use the same private key generated by the main domain instead of generating a new private key from this server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You have to use the same private key which was used for generating the certificate.

It is one of the downside of sharing ssl certificate between multiple hosts. You have to share the private key. If the private key is comprised one host, if affects both.